# How avoid to extracting same files multiple times using zip4j lib?

Tags: android, zip4j

I am able to extract files successfully using the Zip 4j, but I don't want to extract the same file multiple times, is there any way to achieve it? Assume I have a zip file A.zip, the user clicked on it and files are extracted. If the user clicks on the same file(A.zip) next time I don't want to extract it again. Is there any way to find it with Zip 4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my research on Zip4j, there is no way to find the file extracted or not with Zip4j.